# How to define multiple list of different Defined Resources in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I would like to use Puppet to create a single configuration file. This file can have more than one type of Defined Resource, and can have multiple instances of the same Defined Resource.

For instance,

```
define host {
    use linux-server
    host_name localhost
    alias localhost
    address 127.0.0.1
}

define host {
    use linux-server
    host_name web1
    alias web1
    address 192.168.0.100
}

define service {
    use local-service
    host_name localhost, web1
    service_description PING
    check_command check_ping!100.0,20%|500.0,60%
}
```

In this example, there would be two instances of a host Defined Resource and one instance of a service Defined Resource.

This post ([Is it possible to define a list of Defined Resource in Puppet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633571/is-it-possible-to-define-a-list-of-defined-resource-in-puppet)) seems to be a start, but I am having a hard time generalizing it for my goals.

Thanks!

Alan

Answer (score 0):

I'll point you two options two achieve that.

1. Use a **erb template** and a `for each` structure for building your file. [Templating](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html)
2. Use `concat`, and `concat fragments` to build your file [Concat module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat)

Both options will allow you to construct your file, and it's relatively easy. I think I would use erb template if the file is as simple as you posted it, and a concat structure if the conf file is a heterogeneous mix of several pieces.